# How to check whether service method was called from within subscribe()

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I've got a reactive form and during submission I send a http request to an API and based on its' results (success / failure) I'm calling my alert service to display an alert:

```
public submit(formValues): void {
    this.generationProjectService
        .add(
            new CreateGenerationProjectRequest(
                formValues.selectedIndustry,
                formValues.selectedEdition,
                formValues.selectedDate,
                formValues.selectedTemplate,
                formValues.selectedImportant
            )
        )
        .subscribe(
            newGenerationProject => {
                this.domainEventService.onNewGenerationProject.emit(newGenerationProject);

                this.alertService.success('Project was successfully added to Overnight Generation');
            },
            () => {
                this.alertService.error('Something went wrong');
            }
        );
    this.close();
}
```

This works great and I would like to test these however I'm struggling to understand to.

```
fit('should notify failed project addition', () => {
    spyOn(generationProjectService, 'add').and.throwError('up');
    const errorSpy = spyOn(alertService, 'error').and.callThrough();

    component.submit({});

    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

But this does not work.

What do I have to change in my test case in order to have this working. Or perhaps I can make changes to my code in order to make this more testable?

Comment: Just add ` debugger;` inside your method and go to console. It will stop execution there if function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is because you spy is throwing a Javascript error instead of the Observable emit the error, try this way:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

spyOn(generationProjectService, 'add').and.returnValue(throwError('This is an error!'));
```